# The Schema Generator: forcing a field cardinality generates a wrong ORM cardinality

Tags: api-platform.com

the Schema Generator generates a wrong ORM cardinality in PHP file when I try to force a cardinality, short example:

YAML config file:

```
    CreativeWork:
        properties:
            comment: { range: "Comment", cardinality: "(1..*)" }
    Comment:
        properties: {}
```

Generated PHP file:

```
   /**
     * @var Collection<Comment>|null comments, typically from users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, unique=true)})
     * @ApiProperty(iri="http://schema.org/comment")
     */
    private $comments;
```

**Expected relationship:** OneToMany; Actual: ManyToMany.

Did I miss something  ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen from [library source](https://github.com/api-platform/schema-generator/blob/master/src/AnnotationGenerator/DoctrineOrmAnnotationGenerator.php#L200) for generation OneToMany annotation `mappedBy` param is required. Probably, documentation is incomplete.

Nevertheless you can feel free to change any generated code. For example, if your need unidirectional association.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Indeed, documentation is not up to date.